cyrildewit/eloquent-viewable is not working with uuids
I am using cyrildewit/eloquent-viewable to count views on a particular model which I am using uuids.
  public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('listings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->integer('rooms');
            $table->text('amenities');
            $table->float('rent');
            $table->boolean('is_vacant')->default(false);
            $table->string('image_1');
            $table->string('image_2');
            $table->string('image_3')->nullable();
            $table->string('image_4')->nullable();
            $table->foreignUuid('property_id');
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

Throught some testing, I've discovered the package works well with incremental ids which I don't want to use for this model.
    public function up()
    {
        $this->schema->create($this->table, function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->morphs('viewable');
            $table->text('visitor')->nullable();
            $table->string('collection')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('viewed_at')->useCurrent();
        });
    }

How can I modify this migration to suit uuids?

Maybe the model needs this info ?

I found the solution. The migration in the views table needed me to change the "viewable" field to this
